# Push QLPreviewController and set Translucent to false?

Tags: ios, swift

I am unable to disable the translucent property of my QLPreviewController. What i have already tried:

```
 let preview = SideQLPreviewController()
 preview.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false //before
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(preview, animated: false)
 preview.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false //after
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

And already tried to subclass and set:

```
class SideQLPreviewController: QLPreviewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

But still no success - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you present the `QLPreviewController` there is no navigationcontroller at all. something like this could work though:

```
class PreviewController: QLPreviewController {
    var navigationBar: UINavigationBar? {
        return view.recursiveSubviews.filter({ $0 is UINavigationBar }).first as? UINavigationBar
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationBar?.isTranslucent = false
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var recursiveSubviews: [UIView] {
        var recursiveSubviews: [UIView] = []
        for subview in subviews {
            recursiveSubviews.append(subview)
            recursiveSubviews.append(contentsOf: subview.recursiveSubviews)
        }
        return recursiveSubviews
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the viewDidLayoutSubviews of your subclass, this worked for me.

```
class PreviewController: QLPreviewController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }
}
```

Then just instantiate the new class

```
let previewController = PreviewController()//QLPreviewController()
previewController.dataSource = self
navigationController?.pushViewController(previewController, animated: true)
```